# How to run the "other" executable matching the same name found in PATH?

Tags: windows, bash, unix-utils

Is there a concise way to call the "other" executable for `find` available in path that can be found with `where`?

```
C:\repos>where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\find.exe
C:\Users\Qwerty\cmd\UnxUtils_wbin\find.exe
```

For example something like `find~2` or wannabe `whereget find -n 2 -- <arguments for find here>`

Answer (score 1):

Calling an executable without the full path will always find and use the first matching filename by searching the directories in `$PATH`. For your example, if you always want to use the git `find`, simply ensure that the path to it appears in your `$PATH` *before* the Windows `find`. If this is unsatisfactory or impossible (e.g., due to policy), you should either create an alias in `bash` for it, or always call it using the full pathname.

Answer (score 0):

I will just put it here

```
$ alias whereget='_whereget() { A=$1; B=$2; shift 2; eval \"$(where $B | head -$A | tail -1)\" $@; }; _whereget'
$ whereget 2 find . -type d
```

*Unfortunately this solution only works in bash, not in Windows cmd.*

Comment: The alias won't  work either in a bash script.

Comment: Interesting, it only works in the active console. Would you mind clarifying why? @xenoid

Comment: Because when you run a script, it's a new bash instance in which the alias is not defined (only properly exported environment variables are inherited from the parent). If your "source" the file, it is run in the same bash instance, and the alias is used. And I don't see a way to define the alias for a script, since on the interactive bash instances read the profile files (`.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`).

Comment: Right, then I will put it to `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: won't work, because, as I said .bashrc is only used by interactive shells. It is not run by instances of `bash` that are started to run scripts. And you can't use functions for the same reason.